# How to don't allow recreating data base only in local

Tags: c#, git, unit-testing

I have `DataProvider` that has `InitiateDataBase` method.

```
    void InitiateDataBase()
    {
        //Some codes before...

        if (ShouldRecreateDataBase())
        {
            DeleateDataBase();
            CreateDataBase();
        }

        //Some codes after...
    }
```

In tests I'm using `DataProvider` (I'm creating instance of `DataProvider` in TestInitializing ). In local when I change model and run some tests, data base recreates. But I don't want always recreate data base in local (It takes several minutes). In server side it should always recreate data base. I wanna create app that allows me to choose 'recreate data base or not', but how can I do this?

Comment: Simple way - add a boolean parameter to InitiateDatabase, probably with a default value of true, and then when you call it in test scenarios you can add `false` when you don't want to.

Comment: So, In local I assign false. I run my tests. It will not recreate db. It's fine. But when I want to merge my change to develop branch, I should assign true to it, should I ?

Comment: Ideally you'd be running all your tests as unit tests and they don't recreate the database (or it happens once before all the unit tests run).  When you deploy to live you don't change anything if the function takes a bool parameter with a default value of true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [#if directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if), so when you use the Debug version nothing happens to the database. In the production environment you use the Release version

```
void InitiateDataBase()
{
    //Some codes before...

    if (ShouldRecreateDataBase())
    {
#if !DEBUG
        DeleateDataBase();
        CreateDataBase();
#endif
    }

    //Some codes after...
  }
```

Comment: What if I want to recreate data base while I'm running unit tests?

Comment: You can have your own diretives. So when you run the Project only chose the configuration, when you run in debug the diretive DEBUG is autoassigned. For example you can  have 2 debug build configurations, 1 to delete and other do keep. And use something like #if KEEPDB

Comment: I use like this do avoid changes in code before publish. And you can test the debug version in other machines without losing control of the code changes... and avoid publish unwanted code to Prodution.